# Node JS Socket.IO Emitter (and redis)

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io, socket.io-1.0, socket.io-redis

I'll give a small premise of what I'm trying to do. I have a game concept in mind which requires multiple players sitting around a table somewhat like poker.

The normal interaction between different players is easy to handle via socket.io in conjunction with node js.

What I'm having a hard time figuring out is; I have a cron job which is running in another process which gets new information every minute which then needs to be sent to each of those players. Since this is a different process I'm not sure how I send certain clients this information.

socket.io does have information for this and I'm quoting it below:

> In some cases, you might want to emit events to sockets in Socket.IO namespaces / rooms from outside the context of your Socket.IO processes.
>   There’s several ways to tackle this problem, like implementing your own channel to send messages into the process.
>   To facilitate this use case, we created two modules:
>   socket.io-redis
>   socket.io-emitter

From what I understand I need these two modules to do what I mentioned earlier. What I do not understand however is why is redis in the equation when I just need to send some messages.

Is it used to just store the messages temporarily?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to achieve this if you just need to emit after an external event. It depend on what you're using for getting those new data to send :

```js
/*    if the other process is an http post incoming you can use for example
 express and use your io object in a custom middleware : */

//pass the io in the req object
app.use( '/incoming', (req, res, next) => {
      req.io = io;
})  

//then you can do : 

app.post('/incoming', (req, res, next) => {
   req.io.emit('incoming', req.body);
   res.send('data received from http post request then send in the socket');
})

//if you fetch data every minute, why don't you just emit after your job : 

var job = sheduledJob('* */1 * * * *', io => {
    axios.get('/myApi/someRessource').then(data => io.emit('newData', data.data));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Well in the case of `socket.io` providing those, I read into that you actually need both. However this shouldn't necessarily be what you want. But yes, `redis` is probably just used to store data temporarily, where it also does a really good job, by being close to what a message queue does.

Your cron now wouldn't need a message queue or similar behaviour.

My suggestion though would be to run the cron with some node package from within your process as a `child_process` hook onto it's readable stream and then push directly to your sockets.

Comment: I am planning to use cluster to create multiple (socket.io)processes which I hope won't cause any irregularity. I don't know if forking from those processes is the best idea.

I am expecting at least 10k-50k concurrent connections. So I need the multiple processes through cluster to handle the traffic.

Answer (score 0):

If the cron job process is also a nodejs process, you can exchange data through redis.io pub-sub client mechanism.

Let me know what is your cron job process in and in case further help required in pub-sub mechanism..

redis is one of the memory stores used by socket.io(in case you configure)

Answer (score -1):

You must employ redis only if you have multi-server configuration (cluster) to establish a connection and room/namespace sync between those node.js instances. It has nothing to do with storing data in this case, it works as a pub/sub machine.